# CSS circles look oval on ios

Tags: html, css, ios7, geometry

I created a few circles using CSS that I use as text inputs on my HTML index page.
Problem is that when the font inside is relatively large compare to the CSS circle, the circle turns into an oval.
It only happens on IOS. I have tested the page on Safari and Chrome and it's perfectly fine. Don't have android devices to test.
I have tried using meta flags and webkit properties but no go.

Any hints?

```
            input[type=text5]{
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 270px;
                    top: 340px;
                    display:block;
                    width:50px;
                    height:50px;
                    line-height:50px;
                    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    margin:0 auto;
                    color:#f5f5f5;
                    text-align:center;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    background: #464646;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
                    font-family:Verdana;
                    font-size:16px;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
                    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
                    box-sizing:content-box;             
            }
```

Large Font:
[image]

Small Font
[image]

Comment: Your CSS code would help.

Comment: What do you mean by a "CSS circle"? Can you post the CSS rules you're using?

Comment: do you mean you used border-radius:100%; on a div or image?

Comment: Seems like the box is being stretched by the input even with a `width` and `height` set.  Maybe try setting `overflow: hidden` and see if that helps?

Comment: Tried the overflow but no go.

Comment: The right answer is commented below. We need to add `padding: 0;`

Answer (score 27):

well guys, I figured out after playing a bit with CSS properties. For some reason iOS was adding padding to the text. Interesting that none of the desktop browsers added padding. In any case adding: `padding: 0px;` solved it.

Comment: Legend! I was racking my brains as to why my simple circles looked fine on desktop but not on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

**One More Way...**

If you apply CSS3 Property `box-sizing:border-box;` on element being oval in iOS, the problem will be solved.